# How to use an array to go through a for loop?

Tags: c, arrays

I am using ch to try and make a for loop for an array that will produce twice the value of the array right before it, but I keep on getting the same error message. Oh, I am also creating this in ch, so I am not sure if my error has to do with that or if my code is just flawed. Here is my code so far, and I feel as if it should work, but I know I am missing something:

```
ch> int a[10]
ch> int i
ch> for (i=1; i<10; i++)\
ch>     a[i] = 2 * a[i-1]
```

that is my code and I expect this output

```
ch> a[9]
512
```

but instead I get

```
ch> a[9]
0
```

I would like to be able to print all 9 values as a list side by side, right justified, in a for loop i.e.

```
0  1
1  2
2  4
3  8
4 16
5 32
```

And when I try to right justify it as so printf("%i %-5i", i, a[i]);

I get the error Warning: subscript value 10 greater than upper limit 9

```
 10 512
```

when I would like ti to be printed as above.

Comment: "but I keep on getting the same error message" I don't think so. At least, I see none in your question. If there had been an error, you'd surely have told us, wouldn't you?

Comment: BTW, what is this ominous `ch`?

Comment: `Ch` is a C interpreter for education from http://www.softintegration.com

Comment: looks like an off by one error - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error - you start your loop with `i=1`, when it should be zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you haven't initialized `a[0]`, which is probably set to 0 by default. Since `a[1] = 2*a[0]` it will equal 0, and all the following values will be 0 as well.

Do `a[0] = 1` before the start of the loop and you'll get the powers of two as you'll then have:

```
a[0] = 1   = 1
a[1] = 1*2 = 2
a[2] = 2*2 = 4
...
```

Comment: It might be equal to `0`. It's undefined, but happened to be `0` for the OP.

Comment: Changed "will be" to "probably is".